# specialized function of a specialized class

Tags: c++, templates

Can someone please explain me why is this not compiling...the specialized function of a specialized class ???
In the specialized version of the templated class the specialized function is not compiling.

```
        #include<iostream>
        using namespace std;

    //Default template class
        template<typename T>
        class X
        {
        public:
            void func(T t) const;
        };


        template<typename T>
        void X<T>::func(T b) const
        {
            cout << endl << "Default Version" << endl;
        }


//Specialized version        
        template<>
        class X<int>
        {
            public:
            void func(int y) const;
        };

        template<>
        void X<int>::func(int y)
        {
            cout << endl << "Int Version" << endl;
        }

        int main()
        {
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explicit specialization of a class template is a concrete class, not a template, so you can (or rather, should) just write:

```
// template<>
// ^^^^^^^^^^
// You should not write this

void X<int>::func(int y) const
//                       ^^^^^
//                       And do not forget this!
{
    cout << endl << "Int Version" << endl;
}
```

Thus leaving out the `template<>` part.

Also, mind the fact that your `func()` function is `const`-qualified in the declaration - so you have to use the `const` qualifier even in the defintion.

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=61d7170978b38f7eb553677a23b94eb7-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336).

Comment: Thanks Andy.... I was banging my head for the past 2 hours....I have been lazy enough to create an account on stackoverflow though I read the posts here a lot....

Answer (score 1):

I think you left off the trailing const modifier

Comment: This is my first post to stackoverflow..It took a lot out of me to properly edit the code and I somehow deleted the const ...But that does not help even if you put a const in the definition